# The enabled button is getting disabled after redirecting to other page and coming back to the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have disabled a button by default. When user checks a checkbox then the button is getting enabled. But in the same page we have some links to redirect to other pages. If we click on any link the new page is getting opened and then if we come back to the same page the button which was enabled is getting disabled though the checkbox is checked. How can i keep the button state enabled after redirect?

Please find the code for the page:

```
function() {
 var $checkbox = this.$checkbox[0]
 if $checkbox.checked {
  this.$button.prop("disabled", false);
 }
 else {
  this.$button.prop("disabled", true)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nature of Javascript variables is to live within the life of a page view. If you change between documents, the variable states get lost. So you could just consider leveraging the local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Misu');
```

Please read the docs in details, I think this could be the base of what you're looking for.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage